# Make a for loop wait till a method returns true

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, wait

I want to make a for loop wait till a method returns true.

For Eg-

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
         // for loop should get executed once

          my_method(i); //this method is called

         // now for loop should wait till the above method returns true

         // once the method returns true the for loop should continue if the condition is true

   }

   public boolean my_method(int number)
   {
      // my code
      return true;
   }
```

I don't know how long will my_method() take to return true.

All the above codes are inside a AsyncTask.

I am new to Android Development so any help would be really Grateful.

Comment: go with main thread instead AsyncTask.

Comment: If you are using `AsyncTask`, you have to rely on operation which are done asynchronously. What you asked is for synchronous operations. You can call `my_method()` before `for-loop` and if it returns `true` start your loop. Your current code call this method a hundred of times and I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Use a lock and wait on it.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel I cant use this code in main thread because I am trying to move and delete some files. So going to main thread may cause issues. The number of files may vary.

Comment: You should make clear if you want to do busy waiting (the application is blocked until your method returns) or if you want to execute the method in background and activate the calling thread when the method returns.

Comment: @Mekra I want to call the my_method() 100 times.

Comment: If you want to wait on your method in the loop, use a lock and wait on it in the loop.  Make your method signal the lock when done.

Comment: @mikep could you please provide a sample code so that I can understand it better.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Thanks for pointing out that typo.

Comment: @FlorianS. What I want is that the for loop and the method should run in background till the for loop condition is true.

Comment: @mikep could you please provide a sample code so that I can understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use "iterator for loop" or "foreach loop" instead of just for loop.so every next value of loop will execute only then a previous value along with your method executed.

But for an option, you will require to add all integer's values in an array of integer because both options work with an array.

```
//First create an array list of integer and use your same for loop to add all values in that array from 0 to 100

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
list.add(i);    
}

//Now you should able to use whether foreach or iterator to execute method for each array (int) value one by one.

//Foreach example:

for (Integer i : list) {

my_method(i); //your method to execute

} 

//Iterator example:

for (Iterator i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

my_method(i); //your method to execute

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As requested:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private final Condition done = lock.newCondition();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
     // for loop should get executed once
 lock.lock();
  try {
         my_method(i, lock); //this method is called
     done.await();
  } finally {
             lock.unlock();
      }

     // now for loop should wait till the above method returns true

     // once the method returns true the for loop should continue if the condition is true

}

public boolean my_method(int number, ReentrantLock lock)
{
  lock.lock();
  try {
    // my code
      done.signal();
  } finally {
      lock.unlock();
  }
return true;
}
```

Comment: You should probably mention that delaying some thread to wait for an asynchronous result is in 99% of the cases not how it should be done in Android.

Comment: Thanks. Will this code work if I use lock and unlock  any number of times?

Comment: @mikep Tried your answer but my_method() is executed only once.